# Reading HC05 Output

Tags: arduino-mega, c++, bluetooth, hc-05

I am using an Arduino Mega connected with a motion sensor and **HC05 bluetooth chip** to transmit distance data to a larger computer, process it, and send a data back. Currently, **I am having trouble receiving/reading bluetooth output received from the program running on my PC** which is successfully receiving data from the HC05 chip. I am using the Serial Software library to process serial input/output to the Arduino Mega. Having probed the output of the HC05 chip that serves as return stream of decision data to the Mega, I see that the magnitude of the waveform is around 3V. **My guess is that for the Arduino and Software Serial library to process this input, it must be at 5 volts**, just like the output, for which I had to build a voltage divider so that I could provided the specified 3.3 V to the HC05 input. Clearly if the output at TXD from the HC05 is 3.3V then the Mega will receive 3.3 volts at PIN4, the receiving pin.

Here is a basic diagram without the sensors or motors. Exact resistances are not provided but should not affect the issue.
[image]

I have provided the code below for Arduino-side operation.

```
/*
    This module uses the L293D chip to modulate and power
    two DC motors controlling the wheels of the FryeBot
*/

#include <SoftwareSerial\SoftwareSerial.h>


SoftwareSerial mySerial(4, 2); // RX, TX

/*L293D INPUT 7*/
const int YELLOW_GEAR_MOTOR_BACK = 8;

/*L293D INPUT 2*/
const int YELLOW_GEAR_MOTOR_FORWARD = 9;

/*L293D INPUT 10*/
const int RED_GEAR_MOTOR_BACK = 10;

/*L293D INPUT 15*/
const int RED_GEAR_MOTOR_FORWARD = 11;

/*
    Establish ratio os the rate of the faster slower gear
    to the faster gear to scale the duty cycle of the
    faster gear
*/
const float RED_GEAR_SPEED_TO_YELLOW = 0.97;

/*Constant for full duty cycle for analogWrite*/
const int FULL_ANALOG_MOTOR_SPEED = 255;


const int pingPin = 7;

long duration, cm;


char buf[10];

char current;
String messageHolder;
String message;


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    mySerial.begin(9600);

    /* add setup code here */
    pinMode(YELLOW_GEAR_MOTOR_FORWARD, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(YELLOW_GEAR_MOTOR_BACK, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(RED_GEAR_MOTOR_BACK, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(RED_GEAR_MOTOR_FORWARD, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

    pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);

    pinMode(pingPin, INPUT);
    duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);

    cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

    Serial.print(cm);
    Serial.print("cm");
    Serial.println();

    /* Load the distance value into a buffer */
    String sendValue = String(cm);
    sendValue.toCharArray(buf, sizeof(buf));

    /* Write the buffer with a space after for parsing*/
    mySerial.write(buf);
    mySerial.write(' ');

    /* Stop if too close to an object */
    //Serial.print("current: ");
    //Serial.print((int)current);
    Serial.println();

    if (message != "STOP_MOTORS") {

        analogWrite(YELLOW_GEAR_MOTOR_FORWARD, (int)(RED_GEAR_SPEED_TO_YELLOW * (float)FULL_ANALOG_MOTOR_SPEED));
        digitalWrite(YELLOW_GEAR_MOTOR_BACK, LOW);

        digitalWrite(RED_GEAR_MOTOR_BACK, LOW);
        digitalWrite(RED_GEAR_MOTOR_FORWARD, HIGH);
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(YELLOW_GEAR_MOTOR_FORWARD, 0);
        digitalWrite(YELLOW_GEAR_MOTOR_BACK, LOW);

        digitalWrite(RED_GEAR_MOTOR_BACK, LOW);
        digitalWrite(RED_GEAR_MOTOR_FORWARD, LOW);
    }

    current = mySerial.read();
    Serial.print((int)current);
    Serial.println();

    if (current == ' ') {
        message = messageHolder;
        messageHolder = "";
    }
    else {
        messageHolder += current;
    }

    delay(100);

}


long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds) {
    // The speed of sound is 340 m/s or 29 microseconds per centimeter.
    // The ping travels out and back, so to find the distance of the
    // object we take half of the distance travelled.
    return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

Comment: `I am using the Serial Software library to process serial input/output to the Arduino Mega.` ... Why on earth would you do that when you have *three hardware UARTs*...?!?!?!?!

Comment: I mean is the hardware implementation significantly better than the software one

Comment: Well.... yes? Massively better. You should only use SoftwareSerial when you absolutely must.

Comment: Ill give the UART a try and get back to you with the results. I'm assuming I should keep the voltage divider leading to the RX of the HC05?

Comment: Yes. It's still 5v logic.

Comment: So I implemented the UART approach with the same results, I can transmit data through the HC05 but the HC05 is either not receiving the data that is being sent via bluetooth from the PC or the Arduino is failing to read the data that the HC05 is successfully receiving. My guess is I need to step up the voltage from the 3.3 V output of the TX of the HC05 to 5 V for the UART RX to be able to read this. Perhaps I can use a basic bjt transistor network with 1 arduino output at high at the collector, the tx from HC05 at the base and the input to the UART RX at the emitter?

Comment: You may want a logic level translator, yes. 3.3v is at the bottom end of VIH.

Comment: The thing is I already have the transistor (bought them a year ago) and the source (any 5V arduino output pin). My only worry is that the output from the bjt transistor at the emitter might lag the input to the base (from the HC05) which is probably on the order of MHz. Would prefer not buying additional hardware is possible.

Comment: Why do you think MHz for 9600 baud...?

Comment: You're right. Didnt think of that. Still, even at 10kHz, the bjt wont lag?

Comment: Why would it? And what would it matter if it did? It would lag BOTH sides of the signal and the signal would be the same with a slight offset. Mind, what do you think it is that is used in high frequency oscillators and things? BJTs. They can go to many hundreds of MHz no problem.